# Scrapy process.crawl() to export data to json

Tags: python, json, scrapy, web-crawler

This might be a subquestion of [Passing arguments to process.crawl in Scrapy python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382356/passing-arguments-to-process-crawl-in-scrapy-python) but the author marked the answer (that doesn't answer the subquestion i'm asking myself) as a satisfying one.

Here's my problem : I cannot use `scrapy crawl mySpider -a start_urls(myUrl) -o myData.json`
Instead i want/need to use `crawlerProcess.crawl(spider)` I have already figured out several way to pass the arguments (and anyway it is answered in the question I linked) but i can't grasp how i am supposed to tell it to dump the data into myData.json... the `-o myData.json` part
Anyone got a suggestion ? Or am I just not understanding how it is supposed to work..?

Here is the code :

```
crawlerProcess = CrawlerProcess(settings)
crawlerProcess.install()
crawlerProcess.configure()

spider = challenges(start_urls=["http://www.myUrl.html"])
crawlerProcess.crawl(spider)
#For now i am just trying to get that bit of code to work but obviously it will become a loop later.

dispatcher.connect(handleSpiderIdle, signals.spider_idle)

log.start()
print "Starting crawler."
crawlerProcess.start()
print "Crawler stopped."
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify it on the settings:

```
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'FEED_URI': 'file:///tmp/export.json',
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: But you cannot use this for instance to pass several arguments for example `-o Sachin_urls.csv -t csv -L INFO --logfile Sachin.log`. This will work perfectly when using `scrapy crawl -a -o Sachin_urls.csv -t csv myspidername -L INFO --logfile Sachin.log. Any pointers?

Comment: @hAcKnRoCk maybe something like ` "FEEDS": {
            "items.json": {"format": "json"},
        }` ? source: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html?highlight=run%20from%20script#run-scrapy-from-a-script