# Make scrapy export to csv

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to use scrapy in the following way

```python
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)' })

process.crawl(my_super_scraper) 
process.start()
```

It works with `my_super_scraper`, but I cannot figure out how to export to CSV. I cannot find it in the documentation either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `FEED_FORMAT` and `FEED_URI` parameters as follow:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)', 
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'CSV', 
    'FEED_URI': 'file:///tmp/export.csv',
})

process.crawl(my_super_craper)
process.start()
```

More information about feed export here https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html

This post shows how to export to JSON format:
[Scrapy process.crawl() to export data to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876514/scrapy-process-crawl-to-export-data-to-json)