# How to pass arguments to process.crawl in python's Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to use python's Scrapy library with IBM cloud functions. I want to pass some arguments with `process.crawl`. How can I do that?

My code is as follows:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/"]

    def __init__(self, make=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        init_url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com/"
        self.start_urls = [init_url]

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css(".header-box > div a::text").extract_first()
        yield {"title": title}


process = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'})

process.crawl(MySpider) <-------- Explanation
process.start()
```

**Explanation**

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382356/passing-arguments-to-process-crawl-in-scrapy-python) that it can be done as follows:

```
process.crawl(MySpider, make="Audi")
```

But when I try to do that I get an error in my editor:

```
expected type 'dict' got 'str' instead
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I use the scrapy spider for IBM cloud functions, thus my code is as follows:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com/"]

    def __init__(self, make=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Make {}".format(make))

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css(".header-box > div a::text").extract_first()
        yield {"title": title}


def main(params):
    process = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'})

    process.crawl(MySpider, make="Audi") <------- in my editor I get here an warning expected type 'dict' got 'str' instead
    process.start()
    return {"joke": "Some shit joke"}
```

And when I run `main({})` from the console I get following error:

> 2018-06-22 08:42:45 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console
>   listening on 127.0.0.1:6024 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 1, in    File "./**main**.py", line 30, in
>   main   File
>   "/Users/boris/Projects/IBM-cloud/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py",
>   line 291, in start
>       reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call   File "/Users/boris/Projects/IBM-cloud/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py",
>   line 1260, in run
>       self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)   File
>   "/Users/boris/Projects/IBM-cloud/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py",
>   line 1240, in startRunning
>       ReactorBase.startRunning(self)   File "/Users/boris/Projects/IBM-cloud/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py",
>   line 748, in startRunning
>       raise error.ReactorNotRestartable() twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable

Comment: I did not face an issue when I ran your code and passed in the `make` argument. Could you share the part of the code that uses the variable `make`?

Comment: it looks correct

Comment: @Imma I updated my question.